# Integral $\int \operatorname{sech}^4 x \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How we can solve this?$\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}$
$$
\int \sech^4 x \, dx.
$$
I know we can solve the simple case 
$$
\int \sech \, dx=\int\frac{dx}{\cosh x}=\int\frac{dx\cosh x}{\cosh ^2x}=\int\frac{d(\sinh x)}{1+\sinh^2 x}=\int \frac{du}{1+u^2}=\tan^{-1}\sinh x+C.
$$
I am stuck with the $\sech^4$ though. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that
$$
\int \DeclareMathOperator{sech}{sech}{\sech}^4x\,dx=\int{\sech}^2{x}\cdot(1-\tanh^2x)\,dx
$$
Letting $u=\tanh x$ gives $du={\sech}^2x$ so
$$
\int{\sech}^4x\,dx=\int(1-u^2)\,du=u-\frac{u^3}{3}+C=\tanh x-\frac{1}{3}\tanh^3x+C
$$

Comment: How come mathematica says
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\cosh^4 x}=\left(\frac{2\tanh x}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\tanh x \text{sech}^2x\right)?
$$
Are they equivalent?  It seems the first factor $\tanh x$ and $2/3 \tanh x$ are not.  However I do agree with your method.  Thanks...

Comment: Plug $\DeclareMathOperator{sech}{sech}{\sech}^2(x)=1-\tanh^2x$ into your formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I get it now

Answer (score 6):

Since
\begin{align}
\partial_{x} \left[ \tanh^{m}(ax) \right] = am\ sech^{2}(ax) \ \tanh^{m-1}(ax)
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
sech^{4}(ax) &= sech^{2}(ax) (1 - \tanh^{2}(ax) ) \\ 
&= \partial_{x} \left[ \frac{1}{a} \tanh(ax) \right] -  \partial_{x} \left[ \frac{1}{3a} \tanh^{3}(ax) \right] \\
&= \partial_{x} \left[ \frac{1}{a} \tanh(ax) - \frac{1}{3a} \tanh^{3}(ax) \right].
\end{align}
Upon integration of both sides the result is
\begin{align}
\int sech^{4}(ax) \ dx = \frac{1}{a} \tanh(ax) - \frac{1}{3a} \tanh^{3}(ax).
\end{align}

Comment: THanks for the other solution +1